# How to run a golang application in interactive mode

Tags: node.js, go, child-process, stdio, pulumi

I am trying to run a golang application in interactive mode (so that it will prompt users for information it needs) from nodejs, like so:

```js
childprocess.execFileSync(pulumiExecutable, ["stack", "select"], { encoding: "utf-8", shell: true, stdio: "inherit" });
```

However it uses [this function](https://github.com/pulumi/pulumi/blob/66bd3f4aa8f9a90d3de667828dda4bed6e115f6b/sdk/go/common/util/cmdutil/console.go#L53-L64) to automatically disable interactive mode, if it thinks that it is not run from a terminal. Presumably because [IsTerminal()](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/crypto/ssh/terminal#IsTerminal) is returning false.

Given that I am telling nodejs to inherit IO streams from the parent process, I am wondering what else I can try to do in order to stay in interactive mode when invoking pulumi from within nodejs.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that there were two reasons why it was not running in interactive mode:

1. Running the nodejs program as WebStorm Run Configuration makes it non-interactive.
2. Running the child-process in shell mode makes it non-interactive too.

This works when the nodejs program is run from a terminal:

```js
childprocess.execFileSync(pulumiExecutable, ["stack", "select"], { encoding: "utf-8", stdio: "inherit" });
```